# htaccess: redirect 301 doesn't work properly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

This code is working fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my/project/dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /my/project/dir/index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But now I'd like to force the `www.` within the URL to avoid `duplicate content` (SEO). I found this code-snippet, but I'm not able to integrate it into my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I tried a few combinations but I don't want to confuse you. None of them was working.

How would you extend the first (working) code lines to accomplish the goal? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you just remove `RewriteEngine` from the second snippet and insert the other 2 rows right after `RewriteBase`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks for your reply. I tried this before, result: it ignores the `RewriteBase`. When I try to open `domain.com/users/list/?filter=1` it redirects to `www.domain.com?filter=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of rules and use `%{REQUEST_URI}` in 301 rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my/project/dir/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /my/project/dir/index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```